# Drools DSL custom expander

Tags: java, drools

There is `dsl.DefaultExpander` and `dsl.DefaultExpanderResolver`. Design and javadoc gives an idea I can add my custom expander to the flow. But I didn't found real possibility to do that. Do you see how could I achieve DSL to parsed with my custom expander?

Comment: Some expansion is about all you need for the DSL to DRL translation. So, if you are willing to write your own expander, you don't need anything else. Your expander creates DRLs, and you pass them to the DRL compiler: that's it.

Comment: We are supposed to be integrated with Business Centrall, users should have rules in DSL there, thus BC's expander works. It would be nice to have key (like several existing debug keys) to change expander implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in [KnowledgeBuilderImpl](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/builder/impl/KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java#L1917) (the class used to compile DRL/DSL) I see the following method:

```
public DefaultExpander getDslExpander() {
    DefaultExpander expander = new DefaultExpander();
    if (this.dslFiles == null || this.dslFiles.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    for (DSLMappingFile file : this.dslFiles) {
        expander.addDSLMapping(file.getMapping());
    }
    return expander;
}
```

As you can see, `DefaultExpander` is hardcoded in there, so I guess there is no way to specify any other implementation.

Same thing happens in [DrlParser.getDefaultResolver()](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/master/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/compiler/DrlParser.java#L294) where a `DefaultExpanderResolver` is always instantiated no matters what.

In my opinion, the only way to go is to pre-generate your DRL (outside Drools) based on your own semantics and then to feed the generated DRL to Drools.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your response, I saw this snippet. Have a hope this could be overcomed.